# Where am I going wrong? onEdit - Google sheets script finalizations

Tags: google-sheets

I'm just trying to make some extra additions to my script. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6mDHrXdbvzJwnODPtBEafyBp2tux56NZRHAfB-S9_E/edit?usp=sharing

On the sheet 'Show SCM Category'
When E4 drop down is selected

if 'Updated' then
F1 to become text 'Col1'

if 'SCM Category' then
F1 to become text 'Col4'

if 'Company' then
F1 to become text 'Col6'

I've added a few lines at the end of my script but I don't quite understand where I'm going wrong. 
This is so that I can use the function

```
=query({'Newest at Top'!A1:N}, "select * where Col4 contains '"&B1&"' order by '"&F1&"',Col1,Col5",0)
```

I.e. So that I can specify with '"&F1&"' which column to sort by..

Script is:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheets = ['Sanshiro', 'Yujiro', 'Josh', 'Suil', 'Martin','Show SCM Category'],
        cols = [1, 6],
        writeCols = [15, 11],
        ind = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
    if (sheets.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet()
        .getName()) === -1 || ind === -1 || !e.value) return;
    if (ind === 0 && e.value === 'Update') {
        e.range.setValue(new Date());
    } else if (ind === 1) {
        if (e.range.offset(0, 5)
            .getValue() === '') e.range.offset(0, 5)
            .setValue(2);
        if (e.range.offset(0, 9)
            .getValue() === '') e.range.offset(0, 9)
            .setValue(new Date());
       if (e.range.offset(0, -5)
            .getValue() === '') e.range.offset(0, -5)
            .setValue(new Date());
    }
     else if (ind === 1 && e.value === 'Updated') {
        e.range.setValue(Col1); }
       else if (ind === 1 && e.value === 'SCM Category') {
        e.range.setValue(Col4);}
             else if (ind === 1 && e.value === 'Company') {
        e.range.setValue(Col6);
}}
```

Or perhaps there is a simpler way to do this with something like =if (ISTEXT....?

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a formula. In F1, try:

```
=iferror(vlookup(E1, {"Updated","Col1"; "SCM Category" ,"Col4"; "Company" , "Col6" },2,0))
```

Note: Looking at your spreadsheet I noticed the drop down in E1 so that's why I used E1 in the formula instead of E4 (the cell referenced in your question).

Comment: Thank you once again JPV! You really are a master at this. 
You're creative workarounds continue to impress!

Thanks to your kind support, my whole office at work is reaping the benefits of a cooperative table for a source of information : )

Once again, thanks and all the best!